# PHP Datatables Requested unknown parameter error

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, datatables

I'm trying to use jQuery DataTables with server-side PHP using AJAX and date range filtering

javascript code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#start_date, #end_date').datepicker({
        format: 'yyyy-mm-dd',
        autoclose: true
    });

    var dataTable = $('#data-table').DataTable({
        ajax: {
            url: 'server_processing.php',
            data: function (d) {
                d.start_date = $('#start_date').val();
                d.end_date = $('#end_date').val();
            }
        },
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        columns: [
            { "data": 'idbir' },
            { "data": 'Tarih' },
            { "data": 'Name' },
            { "data": 'Accred' }
        ]
    });

   
    $('#start_date, #end_date').on('change', function() {
        dataTable.ajax.reload();
    });
});
```

server_processing.php

```
<?php
$sql_details = array(
    'user' => 'root',
    'pass' => '',
    'db'   => 'countries',
    'host' => 'localhost'
);
$table = 'collegescores';
$primaryKey = 'idbir';

$columns = array(
    array('db' => 'idbir', 'dt' => 0),
    array(
        'db'        => 'Tarih',
        'dt'        => 1,
        'formatter' => function ($d,$row) {
            return date('Y-m-d', strtotime($d));
        }
    ),
    array('db' => 'Name', 'dt' => 2),
    array('db' => 'Accred', 'dt' => 3)
);



require('ssp.class.php');
$where = '';
if (isset($_GET['start_date'])) {
    $start_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['start_date']));
    $where .= "Tarih >= '$start_date'";
}

if (isset($_GET['end_date'])) {
    $end_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_GET['end_date']));
    $where .= ($where ? ' AND ' : '') . "Tarih <= '$end_date'";
}

echo json_encode(
    SSP::simple($_GET, $sql_details, $table, $primaryKey, $columns, $where)
);
?>
```

**error:** DataTables warning: table id=data-table - Requested unknown parameter 'idbir' for row 0, column 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Comment: is your PHP file name `server-processing.php` as it is in the quistion or `server_processing.php` as it is in your `url` in your ajax script?

Comment: @LiamMorton sorry for typo, as it is in my ajax script

Comment: ok, typos happen so just making sure. if it not a typo then the It would have to do with your `date` value in your ajax. as it looks like you don't have a proper value for it. From what it looks like `function (d)` is the value you would be sending to `server_processing.php`  this would not work. so when you run the ajax script what value do you want `server_processing.php` to receive?

Comment: @LiamMorton I'm receiving start_date and end_date from inputs. I didn't post full html code because I thought it would be very crowded. I didn't understand your answer. Could you please show how to fix that receiving error. Thank you.

Comment: From the explanations the error message referred you to, it appears you are dealing with the "Parameter is a string" case here. _"This will indicate that a column which uses `columns.data` has been unable to obtain valid data to display"_ - so what exactly does the JSON your PHP returned, look like?